# Extract from json with | jq by a given word

Tags: json, filter, jq

Can somebody help me to extract with | jq the following:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "resultType": "matrix",
    "result": [
      {
        "metric": {
          "pod": "dev-cds-5c97cf7f78-sw6b9"
        },
        "values": [
          [
            1588204800,
            "0.3561394483796914"
          ],
          [
            1588215600,
            "0.3607968456046861"
          ],
          [
            1588226400,
            "0.3813882532417868"
          ],
          [
            1588237200,
            "0.6264355815408573"
          ]
        ]
      },
      {
        "metric": {
          "pod": "uat-cds-66ccc9685-b5tvh"
        },
        "values": [
          [
            1588204800,
            "0.9969746974696218"
          ],
          [
            1588215600,
            "0.7400881057270005"
          ],
          [
            1588226400,
            "1.2298959318837195"
          ],
          [
            1588237200,
            "0.9482296838254507"
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to obtain all-values individually by given word `dev-cds` and not all the name `dev-cds-5c97cf7f78-sw6b9`.

Result desired:

```
{
        "metric": {
          "pod": "dev-cds-5c97cf7f78-sw6b9"
        },
        "values": [
          [
            1588204800,
            "0.3561394483796914"
          ],
          [
            1588215600,
            "0.3607968456046861"
          ],
          [
            1588226400,
            "0.3813882532417868"
          ],
          [
            1588237200,
            "0.6264355815408573"
          ]
        ]
      }
```

Comment: Post the input as text. So that we can replicate

Comment: modified and posted as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first iterate over the result array. Check if the pod inside, metric object has the value that contains "dev-cds".

```
.data.result[] | if .metric.pod | contains("dev-cds") then . else empty end
```

https://jqplay.org/s/54OH83qHKP